# Node-RED node for Watson Alchemy News

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, alchemyapi

I have created a new node for Node-RED to get access to Watson Alchemy News functionality. 
This nodes allows to define 'free queries' and simpler 'assisted ones' to look for the news content. Alchemy News API provides many different fields which can be queried or used as an output.

Could you help me deciding which are the most used/interesting fields to have them included in the assistant?

Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the venue for this sort of question. You will do better somewhere like the Node-RED mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red or a similar Watson location

Comment: Cool, a Watson Alchemy News node-RED node is something that will be very useful in hackathons.

Comment: I would say Concept, Keyword and Sentiment.